# Raspberry PI 3B: Problem connecting to SSID

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, internet

I am using raspberry pi 3B with Jessie OS. I connect it to wifi by changing the network setting inside the `/etc/network/interfaces` the file. The setting looks like something like:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid iPhone
    wpa-psk test123
```

The raspberry pi connects to the `iPhone` network without any problem. However, when I change the SSID name to `iPhone_Test`, it won't connect. The new `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks something like this

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid iPhone_Test
    wpa-psk test123
```

Does anyone know why it is sensitive to the SSID name and how can I tackle this issue? I did try different variation of names and it seems sensitive to some of the names.

Also, in case someone suggesting "why bothering with such SSID?". I would say this: I have a raspberry pi inside a device and our customers connect the device to their home wifi via raspberry pi so I don't have power over SSID names. That's why I'd like to figure this out so that it can work with different SSIDs.

Comment: Jessie is obsolete. It was NEVER supported on the 3B+. Even 5 years ago this was not how to configure networking. There are literally hundreds of similar Questions (with answers) on this site. It is possible to use illegal SSID but not recommended.

Comment: Sorry it’s 3B, not 3B+.

Comment: Perhaps the underscore interferes with the file itself. Does the SSID have to have an underscore? If not, I'd recommend changing the SSID.

Comment: Try using current Raspbery Pi OS rather than such an old version

Comment: @SkyPlayX I don't have control over SSID names. I have 100s of customers and unfortunately I can't enforce their ssid names

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately this is out of scope for the next 6 month. I would like to solve it with the current OS.

Answer (score 0):

Most routers recommend SSID consist of up to 32 alphanumeric characters, but there is nothing to prevent any string of zero to 32 octets (32 bytes) being used. Indeed iPhones typically use Unicode character U+2019 "single right quotation mark" in the SSID - which is legal, if very inconvenient.

If you ACTUALLY setup the Pi networking following the normal recommended method in wpa_supplicant.conf "iPhone_Test" should be acceptable.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)